# Applying a command on many objects ? VB6

Tags: vb6

thanks for reading.
I'm writing a program to create a list consisting of 8 cols. so there are8 listboxes and a textbox under each one.
I want to check each textbox one by one if anyone is empty or not. ...and dunno how to do that!

I need your help!
thanks

Comment: Checking that the columns or the  textbox is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using 8 listboxes you might consider using a flexgrid control

but using 8 listboxes and 8 textboxes, you can create them as an array and check them as follows :

```
'1 form with with
'    1 listbox : name=List1   index=0
'    1 textbox : name=Text1   index=0
'    1 commandbutton : name=Command1

Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  If IsEmpty Then
    MsgBox "Textboxes are all empty", vbInformation, "IsEmpty"
  Else
    MsgBox "At least 1 Textbox is not empty", vbInformation, "IsEmpty"
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  For intIndex = 1 To 7
    Load List1(intIndex)
    Load Text1(intIndex)
    List1(intIndex).Visible = True
    Text1(intIndex).Visible = True
  Next intIndex
  Move 0, 0, 10000, 10000
End Sub

Private Function IsEmpty() As Boolean
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim blnEmpty As Boolean
  blnEmpty = True
  For intIndex = 0 To Text1.Count - 1
    If Len(Text1(intIndex).Text) > 0 Then
      blnEmpty = False
      Exit For
    End If
  Next intIndex
  IsEmpty = blnEmpty
End Function

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Dim intIndex As Integer
  Dim sngWidth As Single
  Dim sngListWidth As Single, sngListHeight As Single
  Dim sngTextHeight As Single
  Dim sngCmdHeight As Single
  sngWidth = ScaleWidth
  sngListWidth = sngWidth / List1.Count
  sngTextHeight = 315
  sngCmdHeight = 315
  sngListHeight = ScaleHeight - sngTextHeight - sngCmdHeight
  For intIndex = 0 To List1.Count - 1
    List1(intIndex).Move intIndex * sngListWidth, 0, sngListWidth, sngListHeight
    Text1(intIndex).Move intIndex * sngListWidth, sngListHeight, sngListWidth, sngTextHeight
  Next intIndex
  Command1.Move 0, sngListHeight + sngTextHeight, sngWidth, sngCmdHeight
End Sub
```

Comment: no problem. just don't forget to set the index of the control to 0 (instead of empty) when you plan on loading more of it for an array of controls